# XSL how to avoid NaN

Tags: xml, xslt, nan

I have several attributes which contain numbers. But one of them or several (or even every) may not be defined (i.e. no such attr in xml-file). I need to display sum of attrs, so when at least one of them is undefined I get NaN.

So how can I avoid getting NaN? I mean I need to interpret NaN value as 0, like NaN + 10 + 20 + NaN + 30 should give me 60 as result, but not NaN 
Is it any way to avoid NaN result without conditions, just like var||0 in JS will return 0 if var is undefined?

Example of xml element. I need to sum every attr (attr3 is undefined)

```
<element attr1 = "5" attr2 = "1"/>
```

Example of xsl sum

```
<xsl:value-of select="@attr1 + @attr2 + @attr3"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
select="sum(@attr1 | @attr2 | @attr3)"
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `sum(@*)` to sum all attributes.